# wordpress home page slider - revolution slider

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to set the slider full height. But its not working. I have tried using larger resolution images, but didnt help. Is there an option to make it full height using css. Menu is also mixed and disturbing content.

Expected Output: http://stylemixthemes.com/demo/cinderellawp

My Site: http://breezebeauty.co.in

Page Biulder : WP bakery Page Builder

Theme: Cinderella Theme

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using revolution-slider, that option is on the revolution-slider settings-page. You have to set the `width` and `height`.

[Click here to see image of revolution-slider settings-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqLCJ.jpg)